# .map() function is returning an array of arrays instead of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

Does anybody know why this `filterData  map` function is

returning an array of arrays instead of array of objects ?

I am using a map() function inside another map() so basically I am trying to iterate first map function over the big array and afterwards run it inside the child array.

I just want to return an simple object only wit the data that I select in the second map object.

```
function apiCall() {
    const promises = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url, { headers }));

    Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
      let data = [];
      let filterData;
      responses.forEach((response) => {
        data = data.concat(response.data);

        filterData = data.map((nested0) => 
          nested0.childNested.map((nested1) => {
            return {
              id: nested0.id,
              name: nested0.serve,
              date: nested1.name
            };
          })
        )
      });
    });
  }
```

and this is the json structure that I want to iterate, map cannot
run into the second array from object.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "tryuk34io98i",
        "src": "planet",
        "gwt": {
            "gwtId": 918,
            "name": "Request"
        },
        "serve": "Transit1",
        "childNested": [
            {
                "name": "xxl",
                "version": "001",
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
                "solved": {
                    "id": "tik",
                    "name": "face",
                    "isOn": "false"
                },
                "externalRef": [
                    {
                        "type": "eight",
                        "uri": "git"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "two",
                        "uri": "git"
                    }
                ],
                "project": {
                    "name": "InProgress",
                    "version": "1",                    
                    "active": true
                },
                "used": 0,
                "internal": false
            }
        ],
        "affe": 0
    },
    {
        "Id": "987ytrdfghv",
        "src": "Space",
        "gwt": {
            "gwt": 918,
            "name": "Request"
        },
        "serve": "Transit",
        "childNested": [
            {
                "name": "xxs",
                "version": "02",
                "description": "Nullam sed lorem nec sem lobortis porta. Morbi vitae lorem velit.",
                "solved": {
                    "id": "tok",
                    "name": "back face",
                    "isOn": true
                },
                "externalRef": [
                    {
                        "type": "one",
                        "uri": "http"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "two",
                        "uri": "http"
                    }
                ],
                "project": {
                    "name": "Fail",
                    "version": "1.1",
                    "active": false
                },
                "used": 0,
                "internal": false
            }
        ],
        "affe": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: Because `.map()` always returns an array: `data.map((nested0) => nested0.childNested.map(...))` o.O

Comment: Have a look at `.reduce()` or `.flatMap()` or `.flat()`

Comment: @Andreas hmmm but that is weird because if I'm adding that in the jsx is rendering ok, but I need to expose the data .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution may be one possible solution to achieve the below described output structure / format:

```
  id: nested0.id,         // outer-array "Id" prop
  name: nested0.serve,    // outer-array "serve" prop
  date: nested1.name      // inner-array "name" prop
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
// method to obtain the array of transformed objects
const transformData = arr => (
  arr.flatMap(        // iterate the outer-array using "flatMap()"
    ({ Id, serve, childNested }) => (   // de-structure to directly access props
      childNested.map(          // iterate over inner-array "childNested"
        ({ name }) => ({        // de-structure to directly access "name" prop
          id: Id,               // structure the desired output object
          name: serve,
          date: name
        })
      )
    )
  )             // implicit "return" will send the result of "flatMap()"
);

const rawData = [{
    "Id": "tryuk34io98i",
    "src": "planet",
    "gwt": {
      "gwtId": 918,
      "name": "Request"
    },
    "serve": "Transit1",
    "childNested": [{
      "name": "xxl",
      "version": "001",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "solved": {
        "id": "tik",
        "name": "face",
        "isOn": "false"
      },
      "externalRef": [{
          "type": "eight",
          "uri": "git"
        },
        {
          "type": "two",
          "uri": "git"
        }
      ],
      "project": {
        "name": "InProgress",
        "version": "1",
        "active": true
      },
      "used": 0,
      "internal": false
    }],
    "affe": 0
  },
  {
    "Id": "987ytrdfghv",
    "src": "Space",
    "gwt": {
      "gwt": 918,
      "name": "Request"
    },
    "serve": "Transit",
    "childNested": [{
      "name": "xxs",
      "version": "02",
      "description": "Nullam sed lorem nec sem lobortis porta. Morbi vitae lorem velit.",
      "solved": {
        "id": "tok",
        "name": "back face",
        "isOn": true
      },
      "externalRef": [{
          "type": "one",
          "uri": "http"
        },
        {
          "type": "two",
          "uri": "http"
        }
      ],
      "project": {
        "name": "Fail",
        "version": "1.1",
        "active": false
      },
      "used": 0,
      "internal": false
    }],
    "affe": 0
  }
];

console.log(transformData(rawData));
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments in the snippet are added.

Answer (score 4):

Using the combination of `flatMap`, `map` and `destructuring` can simplify something like below. (PS. Just interpreted the data in your case, Update your data model if you still an issue)

```js
const responses = [
  {
    data: {
      id: "123",
      capacity: 20,
      childNested: [{ date: { name: "foo1" } }, { date: { name: "foo2" } }],
    },
  },
  {
    data: {
      id: "456",
      capacity: 40,
      childNested: [{ date: { name: "bar" } }],
    },
  },
];

const output = responses.flatMap(({ data }) =>
  data.childNested.map(({ date: { name } }) => ({
    id: data.id,
    name: data.capacity,
    date: name,
  }))
);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This is looking good but I'm not sure why is crashing on the map function, however my json data looks a bit different, I've just edit the post, can you please look a bit into the json structure.

Comment: It would be very helpful for members to answer if the question has what is the input currently, what is the expected output format/structure desired. Since the question has been updated with the actual input structure, would you also please update it with the expected / desired output structure. Also: in the input/json posted/updated in the question there is no prop `capacity` in the `nested0` level. Where is this coming from?

Comment: @jsN00b got it, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the nested Map Function, First Map returns a second map.
Both Maps will return an array.

Comment: I get it but why on jsx is working ? `data.map((nested0, index) =>
            nested0.childNested((nested1) => (
              <tbody key={index}> ......`

Comment: Because react doesn't care how deeply you nest arrays.

Comment: @CherryDT mmm, oke, do you know any other methods how to iterate through a nest json and expose the data ?

Comment: As was already mentioned in the comments above, all you need to do is to flatten the array. You can either replace the outer `map` with `flatMap` or call `.flat()` on the result.